# Any technology for full body video with slides in Zoom?

Tags: video, zoom-meeting

Given the surge of COVID cases many of us have to find different ways for giving online lectures. I use Zoom in Ubuntu for lectures and I would like to know if there is any technology or combination of technologies in order to get a presentation in which slides are from my computer and the view of the instructor comes from the camera in a full body view. I would like something like in the image:

[image]

Any ideas or suggestions about software I can use to get a similar effect?

Comment: Kdenlive will do what you need, but it'll take a bit of practice so that your body is always in proper focus. This is something that some of my colleagues have done when delivering their lectures and presentations as a result of COVID. We don't talk about "the early videos" publicly, though 

Comment: @matigo Thank you! I was looking for a synchronous video solution.